# Failed to run zmq

Tags: java, zeromq

I have a java code but I need to enhance it using zmq libraries.
After adding the relevant libraries, I get the below error when running the code. The image (`libjzmq.dylib`) which they say is not found is present under the lib directory.

Has anyone faced this issue before and point me in the right direction. I am running this on my Mac. The files present in the Lib dir relevant to zmq are  :

> libjzmq.0.dylib libjzmq.a libjzmq.dylib libjzmq.la libthrift-0.9.0.jar
>   jython-2.5.2.jar zmq.jar

Comment: I ma not able to post the error message , i used code blocks but it doesn't allow me to post

Comment: What is your environment? An IDE? or command line? how do you compile and run your program?

Comment: Sounds like you need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to this *Lib dir*.